# Goroutine size in Golang is not increasing linearly

Tags: go

For the following code:

```
const LOOPNUM int = 200000

func main() {
    z := make(chan int16)
    for i := 0; i < LOOPNUM; i++ {
        go test(z)
    }
}

func test(a chan<- int16) {
    a <- -1
}
```

I ran the code with LOOPNUM = 200k and 400k, and the memory usage is like the following:

[image: goroutine size comparison]

Does anyone know the reason of the sudden memory increment after I doubled my goroutines (and any solution to reduce memory usage)?

Thanks!

Comment: What metric are you using to measure your memory? Print the relevant memory stats from the go runtime, which will indicate exactly what has been allocated.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't waiting for the goroutines to finish, so it's exiting before it has a change to do everything you tell it to.  Change it to this:

```
const LOOPNUM int = 200000
var wg sync.WaitGroup
func main() {
    wg = sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(LOOPNUM)
    z := make(chan int16)
    for i := 0; i < LOOPNUM; i++ {
        go test(z)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func test(a chan<- int16) {
    a <- -1
    wg.Done()
}
```

And you should get a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: the above code somehow is not working: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

Comment: @Kyle: You never read from the channel. So of course everything is stuck.

Comment: could you provide some hint about the cause of large memory usage? I ran your code and it behaves the same way as mine... thanks